# Random Quote Button Not Working (Simple) (HTML, JS, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

I am trying to program a random quote generator and am currently unable to get the text to change. I'm sure that It's a simple mistake but any extra eyes would help because I tried another solution I saw and it also didn't work so I'm sure that I'm just missing something simple.

As always appreciate the help and will share anything else necessary to help resolve this. Thanks!

HTML

```
    <html>
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
      $(".message").html("New Message");
    });
  });
</script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<header>
  Quote Generator.
</header>

<body>
  I thought I'd provide some quotes for your edification.


<div id="wrapper">
         <button class = "btn btn-primary" onClick="newQuote()">
           Generate New Quote
         </button>

</div>

<div class= "text-center">
  <div id = "quoteDisplay">
    Quote Here
  </div>
</div>
  <script src = javascript.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/depositphotos_15858395-Abstract-swirls-seamless-pattern-background.jpg");
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font: 400 100px/1.3 'Lobster Two', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

JS

```
var quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3"];

function newQuote(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length()));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: `<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>` <- Don't forget the head. All html elements should be in the `<body>`.

Comment: You've got quite a bit of excess code here for your question.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.length` is a property, not a function:

```
quotes.length()
```

Should be:

```
quotes.length
```

Comment: That fixed it. Boy do I feel silly but I do appreciate it!